# How can I tell varnish from polyurethane?

Tags: front-door

I am applying a maintenance coating to a finished entrance door in good condition. How can I determine if the existing coating is varnish or polyurethane?

Comment: I suggest you stop by the [woodworking.se] sister site. Loads of info there on how to identify existing finishes and what can/cannot be applied over what. This question would probably be closed as a duplicate there.

Comment: Some varnishes are made of polyurethane, so it's not either-or.